# Get_context_data breaking breaking django listview

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a listview that displays membership pricing, but when the user is not logged in the membership objects don't show up, so there is no pricing. It does work when I am logged in.

However, when i completely remove the def get_context_data function from my views.py, it works and the membership list object appears for non authenticated users.

So somehow the get_context_data is breaking my model=membership query for non authenticated users.

Any idea?

**membership_list.html**

```
{% for object in membership_list %}
          <td><span>${{ object.price }}</span><span class="text-muted">/mo</span></td>
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
class MembershipSelectView(ListView):
    model = Membership
    context_object_name = 'membership_list'
    ordering = ['price']
    #Check if user is logged in first

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            current_membership = get_user_membership(self.request)
            context['current_membership'] = str(current_membership.membership)
            return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you're not returning a `context` for non-authenticated users. If a user isn't authenticated, the context passed into the template is going to be `None` which could mess with methods of the `ListView` parent class. I'd have to see the specific error message to be sure, but unless there's more to the code than posted, that seems like a likely culprit.

Put the call to the `super` method outside of the `if self.request.user.is_authenticated` and also take the `return context` out of there.

```
class MembershipSelectView(ListView):
    model = Membership
    context_object_name = 'membership_list'
    ordering = ['price']
    #Check if user is logged in first

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:  
            current_membership = get_user_membership(self.request)
            context['current_membership'] = str(current_membership.membership)
        return context
```

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear!